# MVC passing list from controller to viewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

im using a example code to understand viewbag.
here is a bunch of code

in controller :

```
 List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        dropdownItems.AddRange(new[]{
                        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option One", Value = "1" },
                        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option Two", Value = "2" },
                        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option Three", Value = "3" }});
        ViewBag.dropdownItems = dropdownItems;
        return View();
```

in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Types", ViewBag.dropdownItems as List<SelectListItem>)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Types)
```

the example was using ViewData, i use here viewbag to practice ..

`@Html.DropDownList("Types", ViewBag.dropdownItems as List<SelectListItem>)` is used for dropdown part.. but what is the use of `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Types)` here..??

i remove `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Types)` and the result is remain same.. My question is what is the actual impact of it and why should we use it ...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related at all.

When building your models in MVC, you add metadata notations to it like

```
[Required]
string Name {get; set;}
```

Now in the view,when you add

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

In this place a validation message would show if the name text-input wasn't filled.